# How to align some lines under {align*}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I usually use `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` to align some texts. Here is a special case I would like to realize:

```
abcdefghijklmn
   hijklmn
opqrstuvwxyz
   hijklmn
```

There are 2 rules:

1) I want to left-adjust the 1st line and the 3rd line

2) I want to adjust the beginning of the 2nd line and 4th line to a special location of the 1st line (for instance under 'd').

Could anyone help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

It's more usual to use `tabular` for text. The amsmath `align*` environment and friends are intended for equations (details [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math)).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} %Probably needed in document classes other than minimal.
\begin{tabular}{ll}
abc&defghijklmn \\
&hijklmn     \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{opqrstuvwxyz}   \\
&hijklmn
\end{tabular}
%                                                                               
\begin{align*}
\textrm{abc}&\textrm{defghijklmn} \\
            &\textrm{hijklmn}     \\
\textrm{opq}&\textrm{rstuvwxyz}   \\
            &\textrm{hijklmn}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can find more details of tabular in the [Not So Short Guide to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. But I do not think it answers to my question: for the {align*} part, the 1st line and the 3rd line are not always left-adjusted; for the {tabular}{ll} part, I do not want to force the 2nd line and the 4th line to be aligned somewhere with the 3rd line... Hope my request is clear...

Comment: By the  way, what I write are usually formulas instead of texts, that is one reason why I use {align*} more often...

Comment: I've fixed the solution with `tabular`. I don't have any more time now, but for equations I think you could try `array` instead of `align*`.

Comment: I get a gap between the parts of the first line.  You should also do `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` and then they will be flush.

Comment: @Ryan --- Thanks. In the `minimal` document class, `tabcolsep` is zero by default, so I missed this.

Comment: @Ian: I had a feeling that's what happened.  I didn't even know there was a `minimal` class.

Answer (score 2):

I know this will not be what you expect as you want to deal with math mode material (you should reformulate your question to make it clear), but a very simple-minded approach with the data given in your formulation would just be:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\noindent abcdefghijklmn\\
\phantom{abc}hijklmn\\
opqrstuvwxyz\\
\phantom{abc}hijklmn
\end{document}
```

For stuff in display math you should look at the amsldoc.pdf file which documents the environments provided by amsmath.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % first solution
\usepackage{array} % second solution
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&abc&&defghijklmn \\
   &&&hijklmn     \\
&\mathrlap{opqrstuvwxyz} \\
&&&hijklmn
\end{alignat*}

\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{2}{>{\displaystyle}l}}
abc&defghijklmn \\
   &hijklmn     \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{opqrstuvwxyz} \\
   &hijklmn
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, a real life example would be better, especially if there is spacing to respect.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. The bounty was accidentally given to Ian Thompson.